# calcular valor de input con otros dos, dependiendo los dos que se llenen primero se calcula uno de los input?

Tags: javascript, html, entrada

tengo tres input (costo, utilidad, precio) y quiero hacer lo siguiente: si se escribe en costo y en utilidad que se calcule el precio, en caso de que se escriba en costo y en precio que se calcule la utilidad. Este es mi codigo javascript:

archivo calc.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").on("change", function() {
calcular();
});

function calcular(){
var costo= $("#costo").val();
var utilidad= $("#utilidad").val();
var precio = $("#precio").val();

    if(precio.length > 0 && costo.length > 0 && utilidad.length == 0){
        utilidad = (parseFloat(precio) - parseFloat(costo)) / parseFloat(costo)*100;
        $("#utilidad").val(utilidad);
    }
    if(costo.length > 0 && utilidad.length > 0 && precio.length == 0){
        precio = (parseFloat(costo) * (parseFloat(utilidad)/100) ) + parseFloat(costo);
        $("#precio").val(precio);
    }
} 
});
```

codigo html:

```
<form action="Productos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="top-row">
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <label class="active1">
            Cost product<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="number" step="0.1" id="costo" name="costo" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <label class="active1">
            % Uti: yes=50, no=50% or 0.5
        </label>
        <input type="number" id="utilidad" required name="utilidad"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="top-row">
    <div class="field-wrap">
    <label class="active1">
        Price product
    </label>
    <input type="number" id="precio"  required name="precio" />
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">                        
    <label class="active1">
        Date price product
    </label>
    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" required/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="Estilo/Login/js/calc.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que pude lograr con tu nuevo código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").on("change", function() {
calcular();
});

function calcular(){
    var costo= $("#costo").val();
    var utilidad= $("#utilidad").val();
    var precio = $("#precio").val();

     if (utilidad.length > 0 && precio.length > 0 && costo.length == 0){
         costo = parseFloat(utilidad) - parseFloat(precio);
         $("#costo").val(costo);
     }
     if(precio.length > 0 && costo.length > 0 && utilidad.length == 0){
         utilidad = parseFloat(precio) - parseFloat(costo);
         $("#utilidad").val(utilidad);
     }
     if(costo.length > 0 && utilidad.length > 0 && precio.length == 0){
         precio = parseFloat(costo) + parseFloat(utilidad);
         $("#precio").val(precio);
     }
 } 
});
```

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="top-row">
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <label class="active1">
            Cost product<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="number" step="0.1" id="costo" name="costo" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <label class="active1">
            % Uti: yes=50, no=50% or 0.5
        </label>
        <input type="number" id="utilidad" required name="utilidad"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="top-row">
    <div class="field-wrap">
    <label class="active1">
        Price product
    </label>
    <input type="number" id="precio" required name="precio" />
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">                        
    <label class="active1">
        Date price product
    </label>
    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" required/>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Puedes cambiar `"change"` por `"blur"`.

Comment: cambie el codigo javascript, replantea la respuesta

Comment: La utilidad quieres que sea un porcentaje del costo o que sea cierto valor? Porque la formula que colocaste primero es para un porcentaje, y la que tienes ahora es diferente

Comment: Hola, he hecho el código lo más parecido a como tú lo tienes, pero igual tiene problemas de sintaxis y no has colocado más detalles para arreglarlo. Por ejemplo, en el código que te puse no se van a cambiar los valores cuando estén los 3 campos llenos y cambies uno, porque no sabría cual de los dos es el que debe cambiarse. Espero te resulte útil.

Comment: tranquilo, la formula no importa, lo que importa es que me funcione así como lo colocaste ahí y a mi no me funciona. si lo coloco en un archivo js y y hago referencia no me funciona y si lo coloco el código dentro del tag <script> tampoco. =(

Comment: ya lo arregle me hizo falta agregar al head el javascript que utilisaste en el head. Gracias por tu aiuda.